# check the syntax of dynamically generated code in c#

Tags: c#, syntax, automation

I am designing a desktop application in C#, which automatically generates code 
based on the requirement provided.

Now I want to check the syntax of the code that is generated.
In the earlier stages we can feed the system some possibilities.
Is there some thing i can do here rather than feeding the system for 
every possibility?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, but please don't use the "pre" tag for anything but preformatted text. Also, you need to tell us what "the system" is and what you mean about "feeding the system".

Comment: Hi, My problem is to check the syntax of the code given. To do that we should be able to write some rules for every possible syntax. Is there any other way i can use so headache of syntax checking can be skipped.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing you *generate* the code yourself, the best way to ensure it's syntactically correct is to generate a syntactically correct code at the first place.

Otherwise, besides creating a custom C# parser and semantic analyzer (a “half-compiler”), you can consider calling the command-line C# compiler, which is part of the .NET framework, and analyze its textual output.

The command-line C# compiler usage and output is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) in MSDN. Have a look on [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) on how to start a new process from your code.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please direct me to a post or website where i can find the usage of the command-line c# compiler from the code.?

Comment: @Prakash Updated my answer to point you to the relevant resources.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check the syntax of generated code would be to compile it.  Let the compiler handle this for you.

Since you're generating it, once you get it correctly generated, it should be fine (provided the design is done nicely).

Comment: if i allow the user to modify the code generated then ..? and how to compile while a project is being executed??

Comment: @Prakash: You can use CodeDom to compile code on the fly, at runtime, on a user's system.  See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command-line C# compiler, csc.exe, and look at it's output. The syntax is "csc Desktop\MyProgram.cs". For a .dll, the syntax is "csc.exe /target:library Desktop\MyProgram.cs". The csc.exe executable is usually located in Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\csc.exe.